# LED Lamps in series

Tags: led

I have some G9 220-240V 50Hz 24mA 2.8W LAP LED lamps.

I assume that in order to power one I need a supply voltage of 220 - 240V AC able to provide 24mA, which is 5.28W. Why is it rated at 2.8W, does it actually only need a supply current of 17mA?

If 5 of these were in series would the power supply still only need to supply a current of 17mA, but at 1100V to work? Would the total power provided by the supply need to provide - 2.8W x 5 = 14W or 1100V x 17mA = 18.7W or 1100V x 24mA = 26.4W

What is the minimum power these specific LEDS can run at?, and how would I be able to find this value experimentally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume that in order to power one I need a supply voltage of 220 - 240V AC able to provide 24mA, which is 5.28W. Why is it rated at 2.8W, does it actually only need a supply current of 17mA?

This lamp is not a resistor, its current does not follow the I=V/R law.

In AC, P=VI only works if both V and I are sine waves and in phase. Since this lamp will use a bridge rectifier and won't have a power factor correction circuit because it is too tiny to fit one, current won't be a sine wave. So "24mA" rating is not the RMS current, it will probably be the peak current drawn by the lamp, on the peak of the voltage sine wave.

> If 5 of these were in series would the power supply still only need to supply a current of 17mA, but at 1100V to work?

Most likely not. Every LED is a little bit different due to fabrication tolerances, and every lamp will use a bit more or a bit less current than the next. The current regulator chip, if there is one, also has tolerances.

When wiring loads in series, the one which has higher impedance (ie, draws less current) will end up with more voltage than the others... it acts like a voltage divider. And the one getting the highest voltage could blow. There is no way to say what will happen though, and ironically cheaper lamps may work better in series. If the lamps are really cheap they won't have proper current regulation, just LEDs so they would act a bit like zeners and work well in series. If the lamps have proper current regulation, then the lamp which has the lowest current will end up with more voltage and blow.

In other words, meh.

> Would the total power provided by the supply need to provide - 2.8W x 5 = 14W or 1100V x 17mA = 18.7W

If it worked, then yes.

> What is the minimum power these specific LEDS can run at?, and how would I be able to find this value experimentally?

You can actually do this experiment if you have a variac. Simply step up the voltage until they light. But the result you get will depend on whatever bulb you test, so don't design a fixture based on that, or it will only work with the bulbs you tested...

Note G9 bulbs are trash. They are usually too small to fit a capacitor, so they will flicker at twice mains frequency. They are also too small to fit a properly efficient DC-DC switching converter, so they will be very inefficient.